# SSL Handshake performance from Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, performance, ssl, handshake

Seeking to improve initial SSL Handshake to HTTPS url from Oracle database.  We're seeing a significate delay (10+ seconds) for the initial callout to an HTTPS URL.  Subsequent callouts to the same URL host return in under .5 seconds.  With java DEBUG=ALL, we see a 9-10 second delay right at the start performing "keyLimits" (see below).  After returning from keyLimits, java runs through a long list of "Ingoring" disabled and unsupported cipher suite messages.  Can something be done to improve performance in this area of the handshake?

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|Root Thread|2024-02-23 11:35:17.663 GMT-06:00|SSLContextImpl.java:425|System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'

javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|Root Thread|2024-02-23 11:35:17.716 GMT-06:00|SSLContextImpl.java:425|System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'

javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|Root Thread|2024-02-23 11:35:26.034 GMT-06:00|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472

javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|Root Thread|2024-02-23 11:35:27.554 GMT-06:00|SSLContextImpl.java:399|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|Root Thread|2024-02-23 11:35:27.560 GMT-06:00|SSLContextImpl.java:408|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|Root Thread|2024-02-23 11:35:27.567 GMT-06:00|SSLContextImpl.java:399|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|Root Thread|2024-02-23 11:35:27.570 GMT-06:00|SSLContextImpl.java:408|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA



SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line(dbms_java.getversion)
19.0.0.0.240116
```

I tried setting jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites  and jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites  to the expected ciphers to reduce cipher volume, but that only seem to make matters worse.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.